# Is there a way to “compile” a list of VBA functions into a DLL file?

Tags: vba, vb.net, dll

We have some customized VBA functions in a script inside an app (not Excel) and they are called by other scripts in this app. We are sharing the scripts but would rather not expose the single script with the functions. The app only calls an embedded macro or a dll, so I’m thinking somewhat “compile” these functions into a dll file, and the project is small so we try to avoid buying stuffs. Maybe transfer into VB.Net? Any idea is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that in Office 2000 Developer Edition... since then, there's no way to compile VBA code into a .DLL, VBA is embedded in the host document.

You can port your VBA code to .NET - I'd warmly recommend C# over VB.NET, because the VB.NET syntax might look like it's "so close" to what works in VBA that you could be tempted to think it could "just work", but it's very deceptive and you wouldn't be writing VB.NET, but glorified VB6.

To name a few, implicit late binding, implicit/undeclared variables, global functions; all are things VBA seamlessly handles, that you absolutely do not want in .NET code. Default/implicit access modifiers are reversed (VBA: `Public`, .NET: `Private`), implicit `ByRef` becomes implicit `ByVal`, ...and so many other little things make grabbing VBA code and compiling it in VB.NET a very frustrating experience.

I'd recommend thoroughly [unit-testing the existing VBA code](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/wiki/Unit-Testing), and then porting these unit tests over to a new .NET solution, and writing whatever code is necessary (from scratch) to get the tests to pass in .NET.

If the VBA code has too many hard-wired dependencies and can't be reliably unit-tested, then it needs to be refactored to allow proper test coverage first: a full suite of unit tests documenting every behavior and edge case of the functionality is the only way to reliably ensure that both the original code and the new code are doing exactly the same thing.

Or you could cowboy it and just port the VBA code to .NET.

Mind, COM interop brings its own set of "fun" problems. Good luck!